# AWS Multi Zone Redundancy - Load Balancer vs Global Accelerator vs Elastic IP what to use?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, redundancy, nlb

I am a bit confused with the Options for load balancing between different AZs for redundancy. I have an application which requires network load balancing and should optimally not depend on DNS to do the load distribution and selection of endpoints. (some clients will not use DNS resolution but connect directly to IPs)

Now I see three primary ways to do this:

1. Global Accelerator - this would enable me to have a global IP address and not only have redundancy between zones but even regions, right? Any drawbacks besides additional cost?
2. Use a network load balancer distributing load between different zones. Here I found that I cannot assign a single IP address to all sites, and while I can attach elastic IPs to LB endpoints in each zone, I can't change them after creation, meaning I cannot "fail over" in case of one zone failure, but would need to rely on DNS (which I want to avoid). Is there a way to do this with load balancers?
3. I can have a warm standby setup by using a Lambda function and re-attach an elastic IP to a standby instance in a different zone, with the drawback that I cannot use load balancing here by default and would not be able to run "active active" in the good case.

I found a lot of documentation on related topics for AWS but nothing specific for this kind of problem. Does anyone have pointers or suggestions how to best implement this?